# In Jest, how can I unit test a method that subscribes to an observable

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, rxjs-observables

I have various methods in my components that subscribe to methods in injected dependencies, that return observables.

I want to write Jest unit tests to ensure that when these observables return / error, my methods do the correct thing.

In the below example I am trying to write a test that checks if `doAThing` has fired. Neither of the below tests work. They both fail with errors like

> 'returnMyObservable.subscribe is not a function'.

```
// Example method to test component 
public testFunction (): void {
    this.myService.returnMyObservable.subscribe(
        ( value ) => this.doAThing( value )
    )
}
```

```js
describe( 'myComponemt', () => {

    let fixture;
    let myServiceMock;

    beforeEach( () => {
        myServiceMock = {
            returnMyObservable: fn()
        }

        fixture = new myComponent( myServiceMock );
    });


    // 1) I have tried mocking with a returned value
    it ( 'should call do a thing when value is returned', () => {
        myServiceMock.returnMyOnservable.mockReturnValue( true );

        fixture.testFunction();

        expect( fixture.doAThing ).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    // 2) I have tried returning an observable
    it ( 'should call do a thing when value is returned', () => {
        myServiceMock.returnMyOnservable.mockReturnValue( of( true ) );

        fixture.testFunction();

        expect( fixture.doAThing ).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a few other errors else where that were masking what was actually wrong with my tests - I have found that the best way to test the above functionality is with:

```
describe( 'MyComponent', () => {
    let fixture;
    let myServiceMock;

    beforeEach( () => {
        myServiceMock = {
            returnMyObservable: jest.fn()
        }

        fixture = new MyComponent( myServiceMock );
    });

    it ( 'should call doAThing when value is returned', () => {
        const doAThingSpy = jest.spyOn( fixture, 'doAThing' );
        myServiceMock.returnMyObservable.mockReturnValue( of( true ) );

        fixture.testFunction();

        expect( doAThingSpy ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( true );
    });
});
```

(This is pretty much the same way to do it in Jasmine too)

Comment: I had a slightly different approach, though I still feel it's somewhat incorrect. 
I mocked the service function to return an observable of my choosing using `of(value)`. I just called the component that executes the subscription inside of it, tested the `doAThing` function with `toHaveBeenCalled()` and added `done()` at the end of the test case. All my tests seem to pass with this setup.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `mockImplementation` to mock the implementation of `this.myService.returnMyObservable`. After that, we can get the function you passed in `subscribe` in the test case(`observer`), then execute it manually.

Here is the solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
export class MyComponent {
  private myService;
  constructor(myService) {
    this.myService = myService;
  }
  public testFunction(): void {
    this.myService.returnMyObservable.subscribe(value => this.doAThing(value));
  }
  public doAThing(value) {}
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { MyComponent } from './';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let fixture;
  let myServiceMock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    myServiceMock = {
      returnMyObservable: {
        subscribe: jest.fn()
      }
    };
    fixture = new MyComponent(myServiceMock);
  });

  it('should call do a thing when value is returned', () => {
    let observer;
    myServiceMock.returnMyObservable.subscribe.mockImplementation(handler => {
      observer = handler;
    });
    jest.spyOn(fixture, 'doAThing');
    fixture.testFunction();
    observer();

    expect(fixture.doAThing).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58815471/index.spec.ts (7.367s)
  MyComponent
    ✓ should call do a thing when value is returned (5ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.773s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58815471

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I Am now getting the error `TypeError: observer is not a function`.

Comment: @TheRyanSmee Please check your code. The code of my answer works fine.

Comment: Thanks again for your patience. I can see why mine is failing and yours is not. In your example, you are subscribing to an Observable in the service. I am subscribing to an Observable that is returned from a method. 
If you change your service to match the following code you will see the error.
`public returnMyObservable (): Observable<boolean> { return of( true ); }`
Do you know how to write a test for the method returning an Observable.

Comment: I should probably add that if `doAThing` has functions inside of it that require the `value` from the subscribe block, then `observer` should be called with that parameter. 

`observer(value)`